# Is any software that write CSS for Flash Builder?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder, flexbuilder

In Flash Builder when i want to change the layout design, I mostly need to do it in CSS. I'm wondering is there a software program that I can use to write out the CSS and i can just copy and paste on Flash Builder?

e.g. when i want to change a button design, i need to code CSS by hand in Flash Builder, is there any program that let me design the layout and write the CSS for me? I don't mind copying and pasting to FB, i just don't want to learn and write the CSS by hand.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's really a good one out there for Flex 4, partially due to the new way of creating skins via extensions of existing skin classes, however here's some links that may be of use:

- [Flex 2 Style explorer](http://examples.adobe.com/flex2/consulting/styleexplorer/Flex2StyleExplorer.html)
- [Flex 3 Style explorer](http://examples.adobe.com/flex3/consulting/styleexplorer/Flex3StyleExplorer.html#)
- [Flex 4 Style explorer](http://www.booster-technology.com/flex4/styleexplorer/)

[Adobe Flex Style Help and Getting Started](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fee.html)

Comment: thanks for the website this really help a lot to get me started

Answer (score 1):

If you use an external style sheet, you can just use design view to edit the CSS.